# What will be xpath of attached screenshot appium- robot framework

Tags: xpath, appium, robotframework

I Want to find out xpath of login button from attached screenshots.
I have tried

```
Wait Until Page Contains Element xpath=//android.view.View[@content-desc='Login']
```

This return successful for finding element 
but  it does not click with below line of code

```
Click Element xpath=//android.view.View[@content-desc='Login']
```

[image: what will be xpath of selected button (Login button)]

Comment: I'm not convinced that the login button itself is selected in the UIAutomator.  What are the fields that are immediately below the highlighted one in the treeview?  One clue for me is that the focusable attribute is set to false.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to check if element is available, for example with:

```
Wait Until Element Is Visible    xpath=//android.view.View[@content-desc='Login']
```

Or

```
Wait Until Element Is Enabled    xpath=//android.view.View[@content-desc='Login']
```

I have attached screenshot after performing above steps.[please check...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Vnfw.png)

Comment: I have tried by **Wait Until Element Is Visible    xpath=//android.view.View[@content-desc='Login']** . element get visible but if I use **Click Element xpath=//android.view.View[@content-desc='Login']**, it does not click on that element.  Test case is getting pass without error but it does not click on login button.

Comment: Is the element in Web context or Application context?

Comment: Application context